# How to download the .mov for later viewing?

Tags: data-transfer, quicktime, mov

I would like to download the keynote speech on

http://events.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1103pijanbdvaaj/event/index.html

so that when Apple remove the video later, I can still watch it later...
but there seems to be no easy way, except if I buy the Pro version of QuickTime?

some meta file shows these addresses, but the first one will save as a 1k file to show the second address, and the second one can't be saved because it is `rstp://` not `http://`:

http://stream.qtv.apple.com/events/mar/1103pijanbdvaaj/1103pijnpfvrbfvijbavojh_hd_ref.mov

rtsp://a2047.v1414b.c1414.g.vq.akamaistream.net/5/2047/1414/1_h264_1000/1a1a1ae757c733980368e14fbe3297c529980f7de958b91d4bac1778e546afdd40af1c4b7cb0e115/1103pijnpfvrbfvijbavojh_1_hd.mov

Someone mentioned using Ubuntu Linux's Movie player to download it but it seems there is no save option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Apple put it's keynotes in iTunes Podcasts, where you can download them.

Look for **Apple Keynote** and download the ones you want.

Just note that there might be delay, often less than a week, before they released the latest keynote.

Comment: I see... trying now... although, would like to also be able to download the ones on web... say, if the one on web has a higher resolution or if it is on web but not on else where...

Comment: this one can be download from iTunes, yes, but would be nice if it can be downloaded from the web as well